# PHP SOAP unsupported HTTP response status 415

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I am using nusoap to get results from a WCF server with this code:

```
require_once "nuSoap/lib/nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("http://example.com/?wsdl");

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("Add", array("x" => "5","y"=>"3"));

if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $client->getError();
    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<h2>Books</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. (soapclient->response has contents of the response)
```

If i try to get the functions from the server it works fine, returns all the functions that I can use in an array. I tried with regular soap too and I get this error:

```
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Bad Request in /public_html/soapScript.php:25 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('Add', Array) #2 /public_html/soapScript.php(25): SoapClient->Add(Array) #3 {main}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and why it doesn't work like it should. I tried different examples and still nothing.